# Moving an image up the screen using do and while loops

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while

I am learning JavaScript and have been developing a simple *game* that is essentially a balloon that you can move around on the screen. I managed to do keypresses etc with a lot of help and the balloon moved about just perfectly.

I now want to simulate gravity, by having the balloon move one pixel down the screen if the balloon image was above a value, i tried to do this with the following do while statement:

```
var balloon = document.getElementById("balloon");
var bottom = parseInt (balloon.style.bottom, 10);

do {
    balloon.style.bottom = bottom + 50 + 'px'; 
}
while (bottom = bottom > 600) // Gravity
```

What I want this to do, is to check the code is working by making the balloon move up the page 1 pixel if the bottom value is less than 600.

I have stripped out all the code I used to make the balloon move.

If I could just see the balloon move slowly up the page I would be very happy, because then at least I know I can just switch the values round when I've added the movement back in.

Comment: That while condition is odd - it will assign the boolean result (`true` or `false`) of `bottom>600` to `bottom`. I'm not sure I follow your intention, but I'm sure that wasn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers address the issue of attempting an animation with an explicit loop. As they have pointed out, you should use timers.

Because it seemed like fun, I made you a simple example of how to use a timer to animate a balloon falling:
http://jsfiddle.net/dmuu9w97/

The key code is the following:

```
// Make balloon fall 1px every 10ms
setInterval(function() {
    var bottom = getBalloonBottom();
    if (bottom > 0)
        balloon.style.bottom = bottom - 1 + "px";
}, 10);
```

Comment: A downside to this approach is that gravity is always _on_. While one may argue that that is the appropriate behaviour, I believe that when programming we can many times ignore the petty laws of physics. As such, we may enable gravity only when necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/dmuu9w97/1/

Answer (score 0):

1. For your while loop condition should be (bottom>600) . No need for '='
2. You are loading the variable bottom outside the loop. It will never change. If it is 610 at the start of the loop it will remain 610 because it is assigned only in line 2 of your code
3. While loop should probably be ....bottom = (bottom - 1) + 'px';
4. If you write a while loop like this, it will execute 10 times immediately and your baloon will be always stuck in 600
5. To solve 'stuck at 600' problem, you should use a timer:
   ***Think about "how fast should the balloon fall". Then you can come up with some number like "5 pixels in 100 milliseconds".***
   Then write a function... call that function on a timer.

Check the setTimeout function here... 
[setTimeout method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible to do with a `do` loop but I think you ought to abandon this explicit loop in favor of javascript's timer/timeline.  Look into how to use [window.setTimeout()](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) where the body of your `do` loop becomes the body of the callback function AND a trailing call to window.setTimeout() passing the callback again with a delay of `1000/your-chosen-framerate` milliseconds.  Then you can also process keypress events in their own handlers for intentional movement.

If you use an explicit loop, you'll *only* get gravity because the loop should never end (just as gravity never stops pulling) and therefore the browser will never have a chance to call the keypress event handler.

Your timeout callback runs once, queues itself again, and terminates.  That gives control back to the browser's javascript engine to process events or, if nothing else, run the callback function again after the requested delay.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this as a solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

[requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) may be more appropriate than `setTimeout` in modern JS implementations. It usually leads to a smoother result for animations.